# InaccessibleObjectException with OpenAPI 3 and Java 16

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am trying to implement a new project with OpenAPI 3 and Java 16. Every time I am trying to build I am seeing errors due to internal dependencies.
This is the error I am seeing every time I try to build.

> [JAVA] java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public boolean java.util.Collections$EmptyMap.isEmpty() accessible

I just want to know if people have used OpenAPI 3 with Java 16 and if did what dependencies they have used.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious and just created a Java 16 Spring Boot 2.5.2 application with `spring-boot-starter-web` via https://start.spring.io. Then I added a `@RestController` and this [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/) dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.9</version>
</dependency>
```

At least that worked.

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenAPI definition",
    "version": "v0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "description": "Generated server url"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/hello": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "my-controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "hello",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "additionalProperties": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {}
}
```